# Dog suffers from periodic mysterious brief, but intense, leg pain

Tags: dogs, health

My dog has been having a strange issue that I have been having trouble diagnosing.  A couple times a year, she will suddenly be struck with what looks like sudden muscle spasms in her rear legs.  She will be sitting around the house, and suddenly she will run across the room, stretch out her hind legs on the floor, whimper or yelp, and try to bite at her hind quarters.  This will last maybe 5 to 10 seconds and then will stop just as quickly as it came.  These incidents will repeat every 5 minutes for about an hour and then she will be fine, like nothing happened.

She is a 9 year-old Puggle, in good shape, who exercises regularly and has no other health problems.  These incidents seem to be seasonal, happing in the spring and fall (we live in Boston).  I have chatted with her vet about this before, but she had no clue what the problem could be and only offered to do a bunch of expensive tests to try to narrow the problem down.  Since this only happens a handful of times per year, and she is fine otherwise, we have never been too worried, but she is getting older, and I would like to figure out if this might be an issue that will worsen and become serious in her old age.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Tried going to different vets?

Comment: @D.Tanya: No, we have only taken her to the one vet, but have spoken with another vet about the issue.  Nobody seems to have a good idea based on our description.

Comment: Is either vet a rehab vet?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship : I am not sure what that means. Both vets work at small neighborhood offices.

Comment: If you join the Canine Conditioning and Body Awareness Group on Facebook, they have a list of rehab and orthopedic professionals. If you don't know, your vet is probably not one. Most general vets are not able to diagnose mysterious soft tissue injuries like a torn cruciate ligament or an iliopsas strain.

Comment: Actually, if you do that it will take you to http://www.caninerehabinstitute.com/Find_A_Therapist.html and https://www.rehabvets.org/Referrals.lasso. There are more links if those don't take you to ones in your area.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I think your comments would make a good answer.

Comment: Has your dog been tested for fleas?